# Lauch Mac Application without .plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, url-scheme

How can i launch application from **UIWebview** without using an info.plist file. I already done with ***URL schema***, But in our case there is no info.plist file beacuse my application is created as ***C++ application***. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you used xcode project ?

Comment: Yes... I created the project in xcode as a C++ console app, so there is no info.plist file.

Comment: There is no such thing as an iOS app without an Info.plist.

Comment: Yes, my app don't have any info.plist file. its a Cpp based application. Same like how we create bundle using xcode. the product is not in .app format.

Comment: Create a OSX application as command Line tool.. No .plist file is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't run the app without info.plist.

Every app and plug-in uses an Info.plist file to store configuration data in a place where the system can easily access it. OS X and iOS use Info.plist files to determine what icon to display for a bundle, what document types an app supports, and many other behaviors that have an impact outside the bundle itself. For better knowledge about this you can see this link:-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

For more explanation you can see this post:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19833263/1865424

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Yes my app don't have any info.plist file. its a Cpp based application. Same like how we create bundle using xcode. the product is not in .app format.

Comment: if its not in .app format then may it work..i don't have the idea about this.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to run the app without info.plist because it is our main file of all the app information & bundle identifier is the main part.